# Area bounded by parabola and line.

Tags: definite-integrals, area

The problem is stated as "Find m such that the area of the region bounded by y = mx 
 and y = x^2 - 1 is equal to 36."

I tried solving it by systems of equations:

```
      mx = x^2 - 1   (1)
```

and the second equation being the integral of [mx - (x^2 - 1)]dx = 36 which gave me:

```
      (mx^2)/2 - (x^3)/3 + x = 36   (2)
```

then trying to simplify (1) and (2).

Is this the correct way of solving the problem or is there an easier way to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are not two simultaneous equations. The two solutions to (1) (if they exist) will give you the bounds of the integral. Then you integrate with those bounds (which ought to remove $x$ completely), and set that equal to $36$.

Comment: Ok. I get that. But how will I get the bounds using an equation with two unknowns? That's the part I'm currently stuck on now.

Comment: @Dgtal12 The bounds are values of $x$ that depend on the value of $m$. So when solving (1), $m$ is some (unknown) constant, and you solve for $x$.